# On an integral inequality involving $L^1(\Omega)$ and bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, let $h\in L^1(\Omega)$ and let $u(t)$ be such that $0<u(t)<R$. Moreover, we set $h_{\mu}(t) =\mu h(t) +(1-\mu)\bar{h}$, with $\bar{h}=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T h(t) dt$ and $\mu\in [0, 1]$.

I am trying to understand why the inequality
$$\int_0^T h_{\mu}(t) u(t) dt\le (R+T)\|h\|_{L^1}.$$
holds true.

I would proceed in this way:
$$\int_0^T h_{\mu}(t) u(t) dt\le \mu \int_0^T h(t)u(t) dt +(1-\mu)RT\bar{h}\le \mu R\|h\|_{L^1} +(1-\mu)RT\bar{h},$$
but I am stuck in here.

Could someone please help me to obtain the desired result?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show that $T\bar{h} \leq ||h||_{L}$ and that $R \leq (T+R)$ ?